# How to get Azure offer details using the API?

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

I was trying to query the usage and billing API that Azure recently recently and saw that I can use the following API to get the rate card:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId eq '{offer-id}' and Currency eq 'USD' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'
```

However, this requires I need to explicity know the offerDurableId, which I came to know for my case from [Azure's website](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/support/legal/offer-details/).

Is there an API that will give me these offer codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no API to get the offer codes. In fact if you look at Billing API documentation [`here`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219004.aspx), they also ask you to get the information about this from the link you mentioned.

> Set {OfferDurableId} to a valid Offer ID code (e.g., MS-AZR-0026P).
>   See [Microsoft Azure Offer Details](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/offer-details/) for more information on the list of
>   available Offer IDs, country/region availability, and billing
>   currency. The Offer ID parameter consists of the “MS-AZR-“ prefix,
>   plus the Offer ID number.

Considering the offer code don't change, I think it is somewhat safe to save this information in your own database

Comment: I agree that offer codes won't change. But there can be more offers added, and some may retire too. How do I update that information?

Comment: I agree with you on adding new ones. However even if they retire old ones, I would imagine that they will still be valid for Billing API point of view. A user will not be able to sign up for a plan associated with retired codes though. Given that there's no API available today, I guess you are left with manually checking the website periodically. Other thing you could do is have a dropdown with existing values in your application and if your user doesn't see the appropriate code, they can come back and contact you (I know, it's kinda lame :)).

Comment: I'll just wait if someone is aware if there is an API for this, otherwise, yes, I have to agree with you :)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is this. But it's  not documented or supported officially. It's the API which the Azure Portal calls to get the offer information.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324041/9893001

Answer (score 0):

There is not public API for this, but there is a feature request, [please vote for it](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-signup-and-billing/suggestions/36518317-get-offer-id-programmatically-through-powershell).